# Problem similar to the birthday problem

Tags: probability, proof-verification

a biased coin is tossed $n$ times (each toss is independent) with probability $h$ for heads. I need the smallest $n$ that lets the probability of at least one head to be $0.9$.

I found p (no heads)=n(1-h) then p (at least one head)=1-n(1-h) then I found n terms of h. I'm not sure it is right(seems to simple) can anyone give hints if its wrong (please no answers)

Comment: To show that this is wrong consider if you have tossed the coin $n > 1 / (1-h)$ times. Then the probability of you having at least one head is $P(\text{head}) < 1 - 1 = 0$, so this says the more times you toss the coin the less likely you are to get a head, and after a certain amount you actually get a negative probability (which is not allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability of tail is $1-h$. The probability the first two tosses are tail is $(1-h)^2$. The probability the first three tosses are tail is $(1-h)^3$.

Comment: I feel so dumb I multiplied n times instead of exponentiating. Thank you a lot

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes one needs a reminder that one knows. There is still some technical manipulation needed to find the answer.

Comment: Yes I noticed, I want $(1-h)^n \le 0.1 $ if I use bernoulli's inequality to say that $1-nh < 0.1$ will the $n$ I find be good enough.

Comment: Take the logarithm, to any base you like. Bernoulli Inequality may not be tight enough.

Comment: I tried setting h to some numbers and you're right,  I'll use $\log_{1-h} $

Comment: I would suggest using $\ln$ (my first choice) or $\log_{10}$. Your suggestion is not incorrect.